# Space in WHERE clause?

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause, clause

I'm coding an account validation system for my new project. Currently register/connexion pages are okay ! Only hte account verification page doesn't work. The confirmation mail is send via email in the register page.

you can register here : http://protect.you-test.ch/inscription.php

you can connect here : http://protect.you-test.ch/connexion.php

The problem is when the username has space this requests doesnt' work :

```
$sql = "SELECT user_key,verified_user FROM users WHERE login='".$login."'";
```

but when there is no space, it works !

EDIT : The problem occurs randomly. SOmetimes it works sometime not (with spaces).

This problem only occurs on this page and not on the connexion page !

Current code :

```
<?php
include("mysql_connect.php");

$login = base64url_decode($_GET['login']);
$login = trim($login);
$login = mysql_real_escape_string($login);

echo '</br>'.$login.'</br>';
echo '</br>'.$user_key.'</br>';

$sql = "SELECT user_key,verified_user FROM users WHERE login='".$login."'";

$req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL !<br />'.$sql.'<br />'.mysql_error());
$data = mysql_fetch_array($req);

if ($data['0'] == 0) {
$clebdd = $data['user_key'];
$actif = $data['verified_user'];

if($actif == '1') {
    echo "Votre compte est déjà actif !";
} else {
    if($user_key == $clebdd) {        

        $sql = 'UPDATE users SET verified_user = 1 WHERE login="'.$login.'"';
        $req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL !<br />'.$sql.'<br />'.mysql_error());
        echo "Votre compte a bien été activé !";    
    } else {
        echo "Erreur ! Votre compte ne peut être activé ...1";
    }
}   
} else {
 echo "Erreur ! Votre compte ne peut être activé ...2";
}

function base64url_encode($data) { 
   return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '='); 
} 

function base64url_decode($data) { 
   return base64_decode(str_pad(strtr($data, '-_', '+/'), strlen($data) % 4, '=',  STR_PAD_RIGHT)); 
} 

?>
```

Comment: echo out `$sql` what does it look like?

Comment: Print out the SQL that does not work and you will see what the problem is. Hint: `mysql_real_escape_string` should be the *last* thing you do.

Comment: echo $sql; --> SELECT user_key,verified_user FROM users WHERE login='TheTime 12'

Comment: thanks ' OR 1=1 ' from 87.197.152.168 :-p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `TRIM` on `$login` variable in your php script. ex: `trim($login)`

Comment: Thanks ! I have added that check but it isn't that. The string I test is clean. Just one space.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, spaces will throw off a string comparison:

```
 'username'
 ' username'
 'username '
```

are three completely different strings when put through a regular equality test, even though a human would intepret them as the same.

You could try

```
 $login = trim($login);
```

to strip whitespace from both sides of the string before stuffing it into your query.

Comment: Thanks ! I have added that check but it isn't that. The string I test is clean. Just one space.

Comment: Yes, but if it's stored as `'user'` in the database, then `'user' = ' user'` (note the space) will return false. As well, what is the ponit of the base64_urldecode() call? PHP decodes all form fields/url parameters before they're placed into $_GET. You'd be double-decoding and getting back 'false' because the data isn't valid base64 when you try to decode. As well, decoding AFTER doing the mysql string escape will potentially make your escaped string unsafe again. escape_string must be the LAST operation on the string before use in a query.

Comment: doesn't change anything if i use or not those functions. Is not that the problem. Try and you will see that it decodes correctly.